# Shimming pip with pyenv

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

How do I get a pip shim in `~/.pyenv/shims`. I am using pyenv, but `which pip` still shows the system version of pip.

Based on the below comment copied from the docs, it appears it should occur through rehashing, but I have run `pyenv rehash` and nothing happen happens

Copied from docs:

`Through a process called rehashing, pyenv maintains shims in that directory to match every Python command across every installed version of Python—python, pip, and so on.`

Per request in comments here is my PATH

`/Users/patrick/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/patrick/.pyenv/shims:/Users/patrick/.pyenv/bin:/Users/patrick/.local/bin:/Users/patrick/npm/bin:/Users/patrick/google_appengine:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin`

and here is my `~/.pyenv/shims` content:

`$ ll ~/.pyenv/shims/
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  12 patrick  staff  408 May 23 09:49 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 patrick  staff  748 May  4 18:10 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 2to3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 idle
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 pydoc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 python
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 python-config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 python2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 python2-config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 patrick  staff  408 May  4 18:15 smtpd.py`

Comment: Do you mind listing the contents of ~/.pyenv/shims and PATH? Are you sure the shims directory is before the system bin directories on your PATH?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I have added my my PATH and my shims contents to the original post for more info.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't have `pip` installed when you originally set up `pyenv`?

Answer (score 0):

All of the shim files actually seem to be identical, so you should always be able to do `cp ~/.pyenv/shims/{python,pip}`.